# How to run a content_script without user click on WebExtension v3

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, web-extension

I'm new to WebExtensions and trying to port a minimal example called [borderify](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/blob/fa4187c2b115459dea7698363a1fe5be4617909b/borderify/manifest.json#L4) from v2 to v3.

I tried the minimal step of setting `manifest.json`'s `manifest_version: 3`, but I quickly learned this breaks the content script running automatically.

[manifest.json](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/compare/main...onpaws:webextensions-examples:patch-1)

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Borderify",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.mozilla.org/*"],
      "js": ["borderify.js"]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

[borderify.js](https://github.com/onpaws/webextensions-examples/blob/patch-1/borderify/borderify.js) aka the content script

```js
document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";
```

[v2 works](https://imgur.com/ljCt6hU)

[v3 broken](https://imgur.com/gMoxQT4)

On v3, it appears necessary to manually click the extension icon in the browser UI to actually run the content_scripts. This seems like a regression -- what am I missing?

How can I get the content script to automatically load the old v2 way? It'd be ideal to avoid needing permissions, if possible. Is this behavior possible in v3?

Firefox 119.0, macOS 13.6

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking at those docs, but what they don't address directly is the new permissions opt-in that seems required now for v3. 

I'll update in an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

TIL there appears to be a new (mandatory?) permissions granting flow with v3 extensions.

After installing a v3 extension, when browsing to a domain that matches it's content_script's `matches`, the extension icon will get a dot:

[image: Badge]

and the user has to manually activate the extension in a separate click:

[image: Manual opt-in]

I can understand the argument for it but it's still adding annoying friction for non-technical users.

I hope to find if there's a way to avoid this extra manual step e.g. with `host_permissions` or some other trick.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. Apparently, they have changed the behavior. The content scripts will not run unless the user explicitly allows running the extension for the specified hosts in the `host_permissions`.

There is a note on the [Content Scripts page at Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts):

> **Note:** Content scripts are only executed if the extension is granted [host permissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#host_permissions) for the domain.
>
> However, [restricted domains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#restricted_domains) can never be accessed, regardless of the granted permissions.
>
> Starting with Manifest V3, host permissions are not automatically granted at install time. Users may opt in or out of host permissions after installing the extension.

Comment: Based on my initial experience using web-ext, it seems like specifying `host_permissions` in manifest.json does _not_ automatically handle adding the perms. (Not sure if it's different for published extensions.) Anyway for local dev I still had to manually approve them in a separate click. Pretty annoying -- I opened an issue on the repo; hopefully there's a trick!

Comment: @paws I use `--firefox-profile=<absolute directory path>` parameter for web-ext. The dir can be empty initially. But once you allow the extension subsequent runs will execute the content script automatically in the dev environment.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds promising. 

For some reason even when I add `--firefox-profile=...` and `--keep-profile-changes`, when I invoke `web-ext run` I still have to manually re-allow the extension permission  I see the profile files in the dir, so at least there's that.

I'll keep reviewing the web-ext source and trying! Thanks for the tip

Comment: Just got it working. I learned it's important to set `browser_specific_settings.gecko.id` inside `manifest.json`. Once I did this _and_ used `web-ext run --firefox-profile=... --keep-profile-changes` it honored the permissions across subsequent runs. Thank goodness.